# move folders up to root

Tags: windows, move

I have a thousand folders on a drive that each have a folder in them (and files in that folder).  that second level folder, naming is all over the map.  sample:

drive

level 1 folder A

- level 2 folder A

level 1 folder B

- level 2 folder B

The goal is to move ALL level 2 folders up to the drive root.  Once there, I can delete all of the now empty level 1 folders.

and again, all those level 1 and level 2 folders have no consistent naming convention.

I really don't want to do this manually! Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Folderpath" -Directory -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "FolderPath\"
```

Or to move contents

```
Move-Item -Path "Folderpath\*\*" -Destination "Folderpath\" -Recurse
```

Comment: thanks man!  that did it.  you just saved me hours of manual drag/drops!